# BAD ARCHIVE MIRROR using PXE BOOT method

Tags: pxe-boot, automated-install, kickstart

i m trying to automatically install UBUNTU on a client PC by using the method of PXE BOOT method....my Objectives are below:-

i m following the steps given in this link installation using [PXE BOOT INSTALL](http://www.howtoforge.com/setting-up-a-pxe-install-server-on-ubuntu-9.10)

1:-the server will have a KICKSTART config file which contains the parameters for the OS installation and the files which are required for the OS installations.

2:-the client will have to detect this configuration along with the setup files and complete the installation without any input from the user.

In my server i have installed DHCP3-server,Apache2 and TFTP for helping me with the installation.

i have nearly achieved my first objective,i m able to boot my client using the files stored in the server,but during the installation stage it is asking me to "CHOOSE A MIRROR of UBUNTU ARCHIVE".i gave the server's IP address and the path in the server where the files are located but then too its giving me error "BAD ARCHIVE MIRROR".

so is it possible that instead of downloading all the files from the internet and storing them on my disk , can i use the files which comes with the UBUNTU-CD, and how to store this files in what format (should i zip them ) on the disk.

secondly i am also generating the ks.cfg which i wanted to give to the client for automatic installation of the OS ,so how should the configuration file be given to the installation process.

Answer (score 1):

Install apache:

```
sudo apt-get install apache2
```

Mount Ubuntu cd and copy all file:

```
mkdir /var/www/ubuntu
cp -r /media/cdrom/* /var/www/ubuntu/
```

Enter http://$SERVER_IP/ubuntu/ to mirror.